# create stored procedure and error in exec

Tags: sql-server

hi i want to create stored procedure like code below

```
create procedure IDnext (
@tablename nvarchar(50),
@ret int output
)
as
begin
declare @S nvarchar(max) = 'select max(id) from'+@tablename
set @ret = 0
exec sp_executesql @S, N'@x int out', @ret out
end
```

and then run this query

```
declare @va int;
exec dbo.IDnext 'courses' , @va output
select @va
```

but i get this error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 31
>   Invalid column name 'id'.

my courses table has id column.

Comment: Is the procedure created in the same database as table 'courses'?

Comment: yes @AksheyBhat

Comment: Please add print inside proc like print @S

Comment: please give space after from  ' +@tablename as explained below

Comment: why it is coming means it is acting like alias name (tablename)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
KeyIdNum    Property    IdNum
1   12  1234
1   12  1234
1   44  1234
1   12  1234
1   56  1234
2   12  4567
3   12  6789
3   56  6789
3   12  6789
4   44  3434
5   12  4444
6   44  9999
6   44  9999
```

THIS IS MY TABLE Iam using same procedure  below

```
create procedure IDnext (
@tablename nvarchar(50),
@ret int output
)
as
begin
declare @S nvarchar(max) = 'select max(KeyIdNum)  from ' +@tablename
set @ret = 0
exec sp_executesql @S, N'@x int out', @ret out
end

declare @va int;
exec dbo.IDnext 'Table19' , @va output
select @va
```

iam getting output for procedure 6 and for select 0
in your code in select statement table name acts like alias name

Answer (score 1):

A few changes

```
create procedure IDnext 
 @tablename SYSNAME,    --<-- use appropriate data type for sql server objects
 @ret int output
as
begin
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
 declare @S nvarchar(max);

 SET @S = N'select @ret = max(id) from '+ QUOTENAME(@tablename) -- give space after "From"

exec sp_executesql @S
                 , N'@ret int output'
                 , @ret output
end
```

Also use `QUOTENAME()` function to force sqaure brackets around the table name , saves you from a sql-injection.

**Important Note**

Also you should really be using `Identity column` and let sql server handle your incremental values. If using SQL Server 2012 or later `Sequence` is another option for you.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers rewards the contributor (in this case @M.Ali has taken the time to provide you with more than just an answer, there are some useful hints and tips here).  Accepting also helps others with similar problems to find a working solution.